# How to deploy to Appengine standard from gitlab CI?

Tags: cicd, gitlab-ci-runner

How to deploy from Gitlab CI to AppEngine Standard environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there are only 2 ways of deploying GAE apps:

- using the [`gcloud app deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) command:

> gcloud app deploy - deploy the local code and/or configuration of your
>   app to App Engine

- using the Admin API. From [Deploying Your Apps with the Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/deploying-overview):

> To deploy a version of your app with the Admin API:
>
> 1. [Upload your app's resources to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/uploading-resources).
> 2. [Create a configuration file that defines your deployment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/creating-config-files).
> 3. [Create and send the HTTP request for deploying your app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/deploying-apps).

Both `gcloud` (used in the 1st method) as well as `gsutil` (used in the 1st step of the 2nd method) are part of the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/), so you'll need to have the SDK installed on your runner.

Summarizing the required steps from a GAE deployment example using the 1st approach that I found in [Getting started with Angular 6, GitLab CI/CD and Google App Engine](https://revs.runtime-revolution.com/getting-started-with-angular-6-gitlab-ci-cd-and-google-app-engine-b1118efcdf69) (probably a good read for details):

- in gitlab set env vars with your GAE service account and project ID info
- in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file's deployment section add a `before_script` section for installing the SDK (update for current SDK version)

> ```
>         before_script:
>           - wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-218.0.0-linux-x86.tar.gz
>           - tar -xzf  google-cloud-sdk-218.0.0-linux-x86.tar.gz
>           - ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
> ```

and a `script` section for the actual deployment, referencing those env vars:

> ```
>         script:
>           - echo $GAE_KEY_FILE > gae_auth.json
>           - ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file gae_auth.json
>           - ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud app deploy --project=$GAE_PROJECT_ID
> ```